# Trying to access member function of one class in another

Tags: c++, class

For an assignment I'm required to create a game using die rolls that uses multiple classes. For `Dice.cpp` I i wrote a function that just gets a random die roll from 1 to 6, and then I need to write a separate class that takes the die roll's value and uses it to determine what piece is added in the game, which i did in `player.cpp`. I tried using `#include "Dice.h"` just like i would for main.cpp, but that still tells me that my `d.getRoll()` is not defined in its scope. I've been told I can't place the `Dice d(1,6);` in main.cpp, but i'm not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be great.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include "Dice.h"
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int playerChoice;
    Dice d(1,6);
    player p;

    cout << "Enter player name" << endl;
    p.setPlayerName();
    cout << "Your name is " << p.getPlayerName() << "." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Time to create a Cootie!" << endl;
    cout << "Please name your Cootie!" << endl;
    p.setCootieName();
    cout << "Add body parts using die rolls." << endl;
    cout << "To roll the die, input 1" << endl;
    cout << "To exit, input 0" << endl;
    cin >> playerChoice;
    while(1)
    {
        if (playerChoice == 1)
        {
            p.takeTurn();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include "Dice.h"

using namespace std;

class player
{
    public:
        player();
        void setPlayerName();
        string getPlayerName();
        void setCootieName();
        string getCootieName();
        void takeTurn();
    private:
        int numLeg, numHead, numEye, numWing, numBody, numAntenna;
        string cootieName;
        string playerName;
        int roll;


};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"


player::player()
{
    numLeg = 0;
    numHead = 0;
    numEye = 0;
    numWing = 0;
    numBody = 0;
    numAntenna = 0;
    cootieName = "Undefined";
    playerName = "Undefined";
}
void player::setPlayerName()
{
    getline(cin, playerName);
}
string player::getPlayerName()
{
    return(playerName);
}
void player::setCootieName()
{
    getline(cin, cootieName);
}
string player::getCootieName()
{
    return(cootieName);
}
void player::takeTurn()
{
    roll = d.getRoll();
    "You rolled a " << roll << "." << endl;
    if (roll == 1)
    {
        numBody++;
    }
    else if (roll == 2)
    {
        numHead++;
    }
    else if (roll == 3)
    {
        numLeg++;
    }
    else if (roll == 4)
    {
        numAntenna++;
    }
    else if (roll == 5)
    {
        numWing++;
    }
    else
    {
        numEye++;
    }
    cout << "Cootie called " << cootieName << " has: " << endl;
    cout << numLeg << " Leg(s)" << endl;
    cout << numHead << " Head(s)" << endl;
    cout << numEye << " Eye(s)" << endl;
    cout << numWing << " Wings(s)" << endl;
    cout << numBody << " Body(s)" << endl;
    cout << numAntenna << " Antenna(s)" << endl;
}
```

Dice.h

```
#ifndef DICE_H
#define DICE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Dice
{
    public:
        Dice(int, int);
        int getRoll();
    private:
        int rollTop, rollBot;
};

#endif // DICE_H
```

Dice.cpp

```
#include "Dice.h"

Dice::Dice(int bot, int top)
{
    rollBot = bot;
    rollTop = top;
}
int Dice::getRoll()
{
    return(rand() % rollTop + rollBot);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, but by time i noticed someone replied to my last question, the response was 30 minutes old. I wasn't sure, but i assumed my question would get buried under others in that time.

Comment: That's no reason to repost your question. Editing it (to clarify what you don't understand exactly for instance) bumps it on the front page. Never repost a question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know that, i'll be deleting this in a bit then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooookay let's see

When you call p.takeTurn in your (endless btw.) while loop you call inside that function "d.getRoll()" - 
that's what's not compiling because there is no Object of Class Dice that's named d inside the method takeTurn

Yes you created an Object Dice d(1, 6) in your main but takeTurn() doesn't know about that.

What you have to do is to pass the created object of dice (in main) to the function takeTurn as an Argument (use & so you don't create a copy).

Because I can't just let it stay there this way: 
Your function takeTurn has this big structure with a lot of "if"s and "if else"s.
Try using switch-case!

ps: again your while loop does never end (don't know if intended)

Comment: The never ending while loop was intentional, any reason switch-case is better? Never seen it used before.

Comment: And why does getRoll() need to know of the Dice d(1,6) if it doesn't use it?

Comment: one word: readability , people reading your code will be thankful ^.^  Oh: I mixed up getRoll and takeTurn (takeTurn is what I meant) (edited above)

Comment: Oh, well the takeTurn function is required to not have any parameters, is there any way of still getting it through somehow?

Comment: well that's sad and bad code then but that would mean if you really have to call getRoll inside of takeTurn you have to create a dice object everytime in takeTurn before calling getRoll (thus the dice created in main is useless and can be removed)

Comment: Okay, thanks, that got rid of that error, but now i'm getting player.cpp|35|error: invalid operands of types 'const char [14]' and 'int' to binary 'operator<<'|

Comment: "You rolled a " << roll << "." << endl;  misses a "cout << " => cout << "You rolled a " << roll << "." << endl;

Comment: oh wow, i can't believe i missed that, thank you so much! It compiles now!